# how to inc a value of a object every day in web application?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, web-applications, web

I am wrote a web application. Suppose there is many objects(stored in DB), I need `inc` or `dec` a value of it at the every 00:00.
And how to deal with it?

There is one way i am thought.
1. run a script at every 00:00 to deal with that.

Comment: Seems fine if that's what you need to do (if the documents need to reflect the new value). What's your question?

Comment: Why not just store the year, month and day? That automatically increments for you and contains intrinsically useful information.

Comment: I want to get a better way to do it?

Comment: okey, i will use `Cron` utility to do it.

Comment: I found that I need to store the year, month and day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on a Unix or Linux system, you can rely on system's [Cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) utility.

Another good option, if you're using **Node.js**, is [node-cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) module, which is very much like system's Cron, but easier to integrate in your application.